# Removing files from github commits within data quota limits

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was using a repo for some deep learning models I have been developing and somewhere along the way large files were uploaded to my repo.

I have been informed that I have exceeded my data quota on github using git lfs.

I want to prune these files from my github repo and bring my data storage within the data quota.

I have pruned my local repos and unhooked all of my lfs attributes but when I go to push I get a GH008 error. I cannot delete this reference LFS object.

I have not been able to find any answers online and am at my wits end. I would think that removing files so that you don't exceed the data quota would be a trivial and fundamental operation of a version control tool but yet there seems to be nothing available.

Anyone have a command for this task?

Comment: You can reset back to the previous commits before you added this file using `git reset`. You can insert the name of the files  that you do not want to commit  in `.gitignore` and they will be ignored.

Comment: Another option is to use `git rebase` for the commit you upload this file and just edit this commit by putting this file on `.gitignore` file after that force the push.

Comment: Yeah, I started doing this and it will work but it isn't optimal for my situation. Will probably consolidate all my commands into a little python script to automate it because cherry-picking all my commits over is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only person working on this git repo and git history is not so important for you, I propose the following actions to fully delete these large files from git history:

1. Remove your git repo from github and recreate a new one with the same name
2. Remove your .git folder from your project
3. Initialize git on your project and add the newly created remote repo
4. Add these large files in your `.gitignore` file
5. Add your project files to git, commit and push

I hope it helps :)

Comment: The problem is that git history is important for me. I have already rebased the repo into a new repo but have also contacted github and it seems like the best route to freeing up LFS memory.